# minimum columns to be deleted in a matrix to make it row-wise lexicographically sorted

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was trying to solve this hiring contest problem (now closed)

> **Lexicographic Rows**
>
> You are given a  matrix of characters. In one operation you can remove
>   a column of the matrix. You can perform as many operations as you
>   want. Your task is to make the final matrix interesting i.e. the
>   string formed by the characters of  row is lexicographically smaller
>   or equal to the string formed by the characters of the row. You need
>   to use minimum number of operations possible. An empty matrix is
>   always a interesting matrix.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line contains two integers and  . The next  lines contain 
>   letters each.
>
> **Output**
>
> In the output, you need to print the minimum number of operations to
>   make the matrix interesting.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> There are only lowercase English alphabets as characters in the input.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> 3 3
>
> cfg
>
> agk
>
> dlm
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> 1
>
> **Explanation**
>
> Delete the first column to make the matrix interesting.

I'm pretty convinced this is a DP problem. I was having difficulties finding the optimal subproblem though. I managed to pass only a couple of test cases

I defined `dp[i][j]` as the minimum number of the columns to be removed to have an interesting matrix.

And for every character `input[i][j]` there are two possibilities.

1. if the previous entry is lexicographically valid we can take `dp[i][j - 1]` and the current input isn't going to change anything.
2. else we check if the `input[i -1][j]` and `input[i][j]` if they are in the correct order we consider `dp[i][j - 1]` else this column is invalid too so we add `1` to `dp[i][j-1]`

My soln. code

```
int n, m;
cin >> n >> m;
vector<string> input(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    string temp = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        char c;
        cin >> c;
        temp = temp + c;
    }
    input[i] = temp;
}

vector<vector<int> > dp(n, vector<int>(m, 0));

for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j < m; ++j) {
        //Left is valid
        if (input[i - 1][j - 1] < input[i][j - 1]) {
            dp[i][j] = dp[i][j - 1];
        }
        else {
            //Current is valid
            if (input[i - 1][j] <= input[i][j]) {
                dp[i][j] = dp[i][j - 1];
            }
            else {
                dp[i][j] = dp[i][j - 1] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
cout << dp[n - 1][m - 1] << endl;
```

Comment: What's the link to test submissions? What are the constraints on the size of the input matrix?

Comment: You can't test it out the contest ended

Comment: How did you solve the first questions (LCS Again)? Even though I tried with space optimized but I manage to pass only 3 test cases.

Answer (score 1):

We can iterate through the columns left to right, choosing the ones whose inclusion wouldn't make the current matrix uninteresting. Properly implemented, this will take time linear in the size of the input.

The key fact supporting this algorithm is that, given two interesting subsets of columns, we can add the first column missing from one to the other without making it uninteresting.